# Convert date and time to Jalali in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, localization

I want to change the time and date calendar to [Jalali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalali_calendar) (Shamsi calendar used in Iran)
in my system.
How can I do this?

```
"language_title" => "English",
"dir" => "ltr", // ltr = left to right, rtl = right to left
"language_code" => "en",
"intl_locale" => "en_US",
"dec_point" => ".",
"thousands_sep" => ",",
"dateformat_full" => "D, M j Y  g:i A", // http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
"dateformat_date_long" => "D, M j Y", // http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
"intl_dateformat_full" => "E, d MMM yy  h:m a", // http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
"intl_dateformat_date_long" => "E, d MMMM yyyy", // http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
```

Comment: You want just to change the time zone of your application ??

Comment: Have a look at the [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) library. It's an extension to the standard `DateTime` object in PHP that adds some localization options.

Comment: @maraboc yes,i want to change time zone :)

Comment: @kryten do you know a simple way?:)

Comment: @HamidrezaGhaderi Carbon is as simple as it gets. Plus, it is very useful. Spending 30 minutes in learning it will do you much good in the future. Also, your question isn't necessarily related to Laravel.

Comment: Did you change it in th `config/app.php` file ??

Comment: @maraboc i want to change calnders to Jalali Calendar :).i am confused

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Jalali/Morilog](https://github.com/morilog/jalali).

To Convert Jalali Date To Georgian Carbon Date:

```php
$jalaliDate = "1399/08/06";
$georgianCarbonDate=\Morilog\Jalali\Jalalian::fromFormat('Y/m/d', $jalaliDate)->toCarbon();
```

and to Convert Georgian Carbon Date to Jalali Date:

```php
$jalaliDate=\Morilog\Jalali\Jalalian::fromCarbon($carbonDate)->format('Y/m/d'); // output is a jalali date string like 1399/08/06
```

Answer (score 6):

Many years ago, I made a third party calendar helper to convert a Gregorian date to Jalali. I use it inside a Laravel service. The main methods are `jNow` and `jdate`

```
<?php

namespace Infrastructure\Services\Calendar;

class CalendarHelper
{

    public function jDisplay($timestamp)
    {
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode( ':', date( 'H:i:s', time() ) );
        $today = time() - ( $hour*3600+$minute*60+$second );
        if ( $timestamp > $today ) return 'امروز';
        elseif ( $timestamp > $today-86400 ) return 'دیروز';
        else return $this->jdate( $timestamp, false, true );
    }

    public function yearList($end=1970)
    {
        $year = (int)date('Y', time());
        return $this->_yearList($year, $end);
    }

    private function _yearList($year, $end)
    {
        if ( $year < $end ) return array();

        $years[] = $year;
        while ( $year > $end ) {
            $year--;
            $years[] = $year;
        }
        return $years;
    }

    public function jYearList($end=1340)
    {
        $list = explode(' ', $this->jdate( date('Y-m-d-D H:i:s', time()), true, false ) );
        $year = (int)$list[3];
        return $this->_yearList($year, $end);
    }

    public function jNow()
    {
        $list = explode(' ', $this->jdate( date('Y-m-d-D H:i:s', time()), true, false ) );
        return array(
            'year' => $list[3],
            'month' => $list[2],
            'day' => $list[1],
            'dayofweek' => $list[0],
            'time' => $list[4]
        );
    }

    public function gTime($date, $hour, $minute)
    {
        list($j_y,$j_m,$j_d) = explode('/', $date);
        list($g_y, $g_m, $g_d) = $this->jalali_to_gregorian($j_y,$j_m,$j_d);
        $hour = str_pad( $hour, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
        $minute = str_pad( $minute, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
        $time_str = $g_y.'-'.$g_m.'-'.$g_d.' '.$hour.':'.$minute.':00';
        $time = strtotime($time_str);
        $time -= 12600;
        return $time;
    }

    public function jdate($datetime, $hastime=false, $localize=true)
    {
        list ($date,$time) = explode (' ', $datetime);
        $dateArray = explode ('-', $date);
        if ( count($dateArray) == 4 ) {
            list ($g_y, $g_m, $g_d,$g_w) = $dateArray;
        } else {
            list ($g_y, $g_m, $g_d) = $dateArray;
            $g_w = '';
            $jw = '';
        }
        $jy=$g_y;
        $i=$g_m-1;
        $j_day_no=$g_d-1;
        if($g_y>1600)
        {
            $g_days_in_month = array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
            $j_days_in_month = array(31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29);

            $div = create_function('$a,$b','return (int) ($a / $b);');

            $gy = $g_y-1600;
            $gm = $g_m-1;
            $gd = $g_d-1;
            $g_day_no = 365*$gy+$div($gy+3,4)-$div($gy+99,100)+$div($gy+399,400);

            for ($i=0; $i < $gm; ++$i)
                $g_day_no += $g_days_in_month[$i];

            if ($gm>1 && (($gy%4==0 && $gy%100!=0) || ($gy%400==0))) {
                /* leap and after Feb */
                $g_day_no++;
            }

            $g_day_no += $gd;

            $j_day_no = $g_day_no-79;

            $j_np = $div($j_day_no, 12053); /* 12053 = 365*33 + 32/4 */
            $j_day_no = $j_day_no % 12053;

            $jy = 979+33*$j_np+4*$div($j_day_no,1461); /* 1461 = 365*4 + 4/4 */
            $j_day_no %= 1461;

            if ($j_day_no >= 366)
                {
                    $jy += $div($j_day_no-1, 365);
                    $j_day_no = ($j_day_no-1)%365;
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i < 11 && $j_day_no >= $j_days_in_month[$i]; ++$i)
                $j_day_no -= $j_days_in_month[$i];
        }

            if ($localize == false )
                $jm = $i+1;
            else
            switch($i){
                case 0:
                    $jm="فروردین";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $jm="اردیبهشت";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $jm="خرداد";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $jm="تیر";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $jm="مرداد";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $jm="شهریور";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $jm="مهر";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    $jm="آبان";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    $jm="آذر";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    $jm="دی";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    $jm="بهمن";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    $jm="اسفند";
                    break;
            };
        $jd = $j_day_no+1;
            switch($g_w){
                case "Sat":
                    $jw="&#1588;&#1606;&#1576;&#1607;";
                    break;
                case "Sun":
                    $jw="&#1610;&#1603;&#8204;&#1588;&#1606;&#1576;&#1607;";
                    break;
                case "Mon":
                    $jw="&#1583;&#1608;&#1588;&#1606;&#1576;&#1607;";
                    break;
                case "Tue":
                    $jw="&#1587;&#1607;&#8204;&#1588;&#1606;&#1576;&#1607;";
                    break;
                case "Wed":
                    $jw="&#1670;&#1607;&#1575;&#1585;&#1588;&#1606;&#1576;&#1607;";
                    break;
                case "Thu":
                    $jw="&#1662;&#1606;&#1580;&#8204;&#1588;&#1606;&#1576;&#1607;";
                    break;
                case "Fri":
                    $jw="&#1580;&#1605;&#1593;&#1607;";
                    break;
            };

        $time = $hastime == false ? '' : $time;

        return "$jw $jd $jm $jy $time";
    }

    function div($a,$b) {
        return (int) ($a / $b);
    }

    function jalali_to_gregorian($j_y, $j_m, $j_d)
    {
        $g_days_in_month = array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
        $j_days_in_month = array(31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29);



        $jy = $j_y-979;
        $jm = $j_m-1;
        $jd = $j_d-1;

        $j_day_no = 365*$jy + $this->div($jy, 33)*8 + $this->div($jy%33+3, 4);
        for ($i=0; $i < $jm; ++$i)
        $j_day_no += $j_days_in_month[$i];

        $j_day_no += $jd;

        $g_day_no = $j_day_no+79;

        $gy = 1600 + 400*$this->div($g_day_no, 146097); /* 146097 = 365*400 + 400/4 - 400/100 + 400/400 */
        $g_day_no = $g_day_no % 146097;

        $leap = true;
        if ($g_day_no >= 36525) /* 36525 = 365*100 + 100/4 */
        {
            $g_day_no--;
            $gy += 100*$this->div($g_day_no,  36524); /* 36524 = 365*100 + 100/4 - 100/100 */
            $g_day_no = $g_day_no % 36524;

            if ($g_day_no >= 365)
            $g_day_no++;
            else
            $leap = false;
        }

        $gy += 4*$this->div($g_day_no, 1461); /* 1461 = 365*4 + 4/4 */
        $g_day_no %= 1461;

        if ($g_day_no >= 366) {
            $leap = false;

            $g_day_no--;
            $gy += $this->div($g_day_no, 365);
            $g_day_no = $g_day_no % 365;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $g_day_no >= $g_days_in_month[$i] + ($i == 1 && $leap); $i++)
        $g_day_no -= $g_days_in_month[$i] + ($i == 1 && $leap);
        $gm = $i+1;
        $gd = $g_day_no+1;

        return array($gy, $gm, $gd);
    }

    function gregorian_to_jalali($g_y, $g_m, $g_d)
    {
        $d_4 = $g_y % 4;
        $g_a = array(0, 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334);
        $doy_g = $g_a[(int)$g_m] + $g_d;
        if ($d_4 == 0 and $g_m > 2)
            $doy_g++;
        $d_33 = (int)((($g_y - 16) % 132) * 0.0305);
        $a = ($d_33 == 3 or $d_33 < ($d_4 - 1) or $d_4 == 0) ? 286 : 287;
        $b = (($d_33 == 1 or $d_33 == 2) and ($d_33 == $d_4 or $d_4 == 1)) ? 78 : (($d_33 == 3 and $d_4 == 0) ? 80 : 79);
        if((int)(($g_y - 10) / 63) == 30) {
            $a--;
            $b++;
        }
        if($doy_g > $b) {
            $jy = $g_y - 621;
            $doy_j = $doy_g - $b;
        }
        else {
            $jy = $g_y - 622;
            $doy_j = $doy_g + $a;
        }
        if($doy_j < 187) {
            $jm = (int)(($doy_j - 1) / 31);
            $jd = $doy_j - (31 * $jm++);
        }
        else {
            $jm = (int)(($doy_j - 187) / 30);
            $jd = $doy_j - 186 - ($jm * 30);
            $jm += 7;
        }
        return array($jy, $jm, $jd);
    }

}

/* End of file Calendar.php */
```

Comment: You can also use this [package](http://morilog.ir/jalali-shamsi-date-for-laravel-5/)

Answer (score 1):

in `config/app.php` set timezone to 'Asia/Tehran' but it saves only time based on iran for converting Gregorian to Shamsi Date you can use [Miladr Package](https://github.com/miladr/jalali)

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use These Two Packages

### Verta

```
composer require hekmatinasser/verta
```

Example

```
Verta::jalaliToGregorian(1401,03,27);

// output [2020,6,17]
```

### OR

### morilog/jalali  php >= 7.0

```
composer require morilog/jalali:3.*
```

Example

```
public function toCarbon(): Carbon

$date = (new Jalalian(1397, 1, 18, 12, 10, 0))
      ->toCarbon()
      ->toDateTimeString(); 

 // output: 2018-04-07 12:10:00
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/app.php` file, you've to change the following setting :

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'IST',
```

Assuming that your timezone is `IST` :)

Comment: What is your time zone ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$wrongFormat = 1360-1-1;
$correctFormat = 1360-01-01;
```

You can use like this:

```
$correctDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($wrongFormat));
$miladiDate = \Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::createCarbonFromFormat('Y-m-d',$correctDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [morilog/jalali](https://github.com/morilog/jalali) package.

1- Run the Composer update command

```
    composer require morilog/jalali:3.*
```

2- Add name space

```
 use Morilog\Jalali\Jalalian;
```

3- Basic Usage

- Convert Jalali to Carbon

  ```
   $jDate = "1400/07/05";
   $date = Jalalian::fromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->toCarbon();
  ```
- Convert Carbon to Jalali

  ```
   $date = '2020/09/27';
   $jDate = Jalalian::fromCarbon($date)->format('Y-m-d');
   // or
   $jDate = jdate($date)->format('Y-m-d');
  ```

also u can use `Y-m-d H:i:s` or  `H:i:s` as format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jdf library and call it easily

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).