# PHP DateTime gives incorrect value

Tags: php, datetime, persian, persian-calendar, jalali-calendar

I wonder why this php code gives incorrect output value.

```
dd(new \DateTime("1397/02/29", new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran')));
```

It outputs below object:

```
DateTime @-18076965944 {#1256 ▼
  date: 1397-03-01 00:00:00.0 Asia/Tehran (+03:25)
}
```

As you see the date is incorrect and must be `1397-02-01`.
The output for values `1397/02/30 && 1397/02/31` is incorrect also.

Can anyone help please.
thanks.

Comment: I doubt that there was Feb 29 in this year.

Comment: @u_mulder It's a Persian date and exits.

Comment: I suppose `DateTime` class does not support your calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP store date object internal as struct
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.h#L137
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/timelib.h#L204

But DateTime init have no validating and only converts given date string to timestamp.
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L2647

Before creating date object you should check it using http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

```
var_dump(
    checkdate(2,20,1000), // bool(true)
    checkdate(2,30,1000) // bool(false)
);
```

Comment: It does not solve the problem, and the `checkdate()` function validates `Gregorian ` date, but the date i'm using is `Jalali`.

Answer (score 1):

The DateTime leap year code applies the Gregorian calendar rules, and they do not work for the Persian calendar.

The "divide by 4 but not 100 except 400" rule is not valid for Persian calendar, which follows a different algorithm:

```
https://www.timeanddate.com/date/iran-leap-year.html
```

Basically, you cannot use `DateTime` for Persian dates. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538273/php-wrong-convert-from-gregorian-to-persian-datetime-in-last-day-of-month). You might perhaps adapt [some other code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28380/Persian-Calendar-in-PHP).

**Update**: actually, it appears different calendars and sources *do not agree* on leap years. Jalali has 1397 as a leap year but Persian calendar does not?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your responses.

As i was going to convert a `Jalali` date to a `Gregorian` date, i was trying to make a PHP `DateTime` object of my `Jalali` date string `("1397/02/29")` and then convert the date object to the `Gregorian` date object using [this package](https://github.com/morilog/jalali). I fixed the issue by directly converting my `Jalali` date string to what i want using [morilog/jalali](https://github.com/morilog/jalali) like below:

```
$jalali_date = explode("/", request()->to);

$gregorian_date_time = \jDateTime::toGregorianDate($jalali_date[0], $jalali_date[1], $jalali_date[2])->setTime(23, 55)->format("Y-m-d H:i");
return $gregorian_date_time;
```

Thank you all again.